# how to know if an image data is ABGR or RGBA from pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

When I load png files with `pygame.image.load` and then get data with `pygame.surfarray.pixels2d`, I get sometimes color data in ABGR format, and sometimes in RGBA, forcing me to a conversion if copy data from one type to another.

Problem is that I can't foresee if data will be ABGR or RGBA, and I comment or uncomment the conversion when I'm working on another file.

Is there a way to know data type from pygame ?

Comment: Can you tell us if there's anything different about the files that come one way vs. the other?  I know Windows .bmp files are arranged ABGR where most other formats are the other way around.

Comment: I didn't find anything. I use only png, either downloaded, or edited with paint.net or GIMP.

Comment: PNG files are *always* stored in RGBA order, see the [PNG Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-DataRep.html).  I'd suggest that one of the applications you're using to save the files is doing it incorrectly.

Comment: The `pygame.surfarray` module has methods to load a specific channel into an array. You could use those and then construct an array from them? https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.array_alpha

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

The [`pygame.surfarray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html) module provides functions for separately referencing color channels and alpha channels of a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object in an array. Use these functions instead of [`pygame.surfarray.pixels2d()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.pixels2d):

[`pygame.surfarray.pixels3d()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.array_alpha):

> Reference pixels into a 3d array

[`pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.array_alpha):

> Reference pixel alphas into a 2d array